# How to print Fibonacci Series upto n numbers using Recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to print Fibonacci series using recursion. Unfortunately, it repeatedly prints the last number.

For e.g; if I input `5` it first prints: `1`, then `0`, then again `1` & `1`, and then `2`, and then it starts repeating again `0 1 1 2` and after that it prints `3`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        cout << n << " ";
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        int sum = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        cout << sum << " ";
        return sum;
    }
}

//====================================================================
void main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Please input the Limit: ";
    cin >> n;
    fibonacci(n);
    system("pause>null");
}
```

Comment: There is nothing `.net` nor `visual-studio` related in this question

Comment: You could declare it like int fibonacci(int n, bool print = false) and call it in the main with fibonacci(n,true), surround the cout with if(print){}. That said, doing fibonacci this way is extremely inefficient, you will do 2^n calculations when n would suffice. This means that fib(100) will take about 1E30 calculations instead of 100 calculations (and will probably kill your memory doing so).

Comment: @tobi303 I dunno, `void main()` is not standard C++, might be a visual studio extension. Hardly merits the tag though.

Comment: It's been 3 decades since I have had to write this function however I believe you have got the algorithm wrong. Shouldn't there be a `n-2`?

Comment: Change to `int sum = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)`

Comment: As mentioned, Fibonacci is one of the worst example of recursion, due to combinatorial explosion. Better cache the result and compute them only if needed (i.e., use dynamic programming).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you want to *print* them using recursion? (The tree recursion makes that non-trivial.) Don't you want to compute them using recursion and then print them? (It's very inefficient, but that's often one of the points of this kind of exercise.)

Comment: Funny thing that the common examples to demonstrate recursion (Fibonacci, factorial) are much easier and much more efficient to calculate iteratively :)

(although the recursive solutions have use in TMP)

Comment: Actually its just for practice and i am still not getting the answer

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: still waiting for you reply !

Comment: Help me Please if you can because i am a little bit confused about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive definition of the fibonacci function is

> fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

so just change

```
int sum = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 1);
```

to

```
int sum = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
```

Testing:

```
Please input the Limit: 5
1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5

Please input the Limit: 6
1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8
```

**EDIT 1**

You would like to print the fibonacci sequence fib(0), fib(1), ... with this algorithm. If you beef up your output a little you'll see how this works for fib(5):

```
fib 1 = 1
fib 0 = 0
fib 2 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib 3 = 2
fib 1 = 1
fib 0 = 0
fib 2 = 1
fib 4 = 3
fib 1 = 1
fib 0 = 0
fib 2 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib 3 = 2
fib 5 = 5
5
```

As you see quite a few values are computed several times, which explains the sequence that is printed. One way to compute each result only once is [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). If you use memoization and only print the first time a result is determined you'll get:

```
fib 1 = 1
fib 0 = 0
fib 2 = 1
fib 3 = 2
fib 4 = 3
fib 5 = 5
5
```

so even then you don't get the order you want. So you'd have to use memoisation and only print the hash map at the end of the process.

```
5
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1
fib 3 = 2
fib 4 = 3
fib 5 = 5
```

Of course, you could also just create an additional loop and print all values for fib(i) for i from 1 to n. That would be fairly inefficient though.

**EDIT 2**

*Disclaimer*: I have no clue about C++. I wrote my last C program ages ago. But the following works, other people will do it better I'm sure.

So here's a simple example of memoization using a plain array, no hash map. Since you didn't say *which* concepts you have learnt until now I hope this is simple enough.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAX 100
#define UNDEF -1

using namespace std;

int memo[MAX]; // memoization of results

int fibonacci(int n) {
    int res = memo[n];
    if (res != UNDEF) return res; // result has been computed before
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        res = n;
    else
        res = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    memo[n] = res; // memoize result
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int n, i;
    do {
        cout << "Please input the Limit (max " << MAX << ") : ";
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 0 || n >= MAX);
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) memo[i] = UNDEF; // intitialize memo
    fibonacci(n);
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) cout << memo[i] << " "; // print results
    cout << endl;
}
```

Testing:

```
Please input the Limit (max 100) : 40
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 2178309 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986 102334155
```

Comment: you are right it was a typing mistake but i am still not getting the right answer , it should be 0 1 2 3 5 ..... etc .

Comment: usepla you are right i can use a loop but i want to do it by recursion and this method is still not acceptable so can you help me a little bit further?

Comment: @usepla if you are there please try to help me :)

Comment: No i just want you to modify my code and apply a condition so that it will prints specific numbers and do not repeat numbers .

Comment: It's not just applying a condition; you need to implement memoization and then loop over the resulting hash map. So basically you have to rewrite your function. I won't have the time to do that right now, but those pointers should get you on the right track.

Comment: OK so when ever you are free please provide me an example of memoization without using map.h

Comment: I am following my syllabus and they have restricted us to code , remaining in the domain what they have taught us

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an implementation, using *memoization*:

```
// header needed for the container: map
#include <map> 

int mem_fact (int i, std::map<int, int>& m) {

    // if value with key == i does not exist in m: calculate it
    if (m.find(i) == m.end()) {

        // the recursive calls are made only if the value doesn't already exist
        m[i] = mem_fact (i - 1, m) + mem_fact (i - 2, m); 
    }

    // if value with key == i exists, return the corresponding value
    return m[i];
}

int fast_factorial (int i) {
    // key (Fibonacci index) - value (Fibbonaci number)
    std::map<int, int> memo;

    // initialize the first two Fibonacci numbers
    memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(0, 0));
    memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(1, 1));

    return mem_fact(i, memo);
}
```

I will leave to you where to put the `std::cout` so that each fibonacci number is displayed once.

Note: in `main()` you need to call `fast_factorial(num_of_fib);`

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void _fib(unsigned int current, unsigned int max, unsigned int oneBack, unsigned int twoBack)
{
    if (current == max) return;
    unsigned int sum = oneBack + twoBack;
    std::cout << sum << '\n';
    _fib(current+1, max, sum, oneBack);
}

void fib(unsigned int max)
{
    if (max >= 2)
    {
        std::cout << "0\n1\n";
        _fib(2, max, 1, 0);
    }
    else if (max == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "0\n1\n";
    }
    else if (max == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "0\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    fib(1000);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
    std::cout << diff.count() << "seconds";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n)
{
if((n==1)||(n==0))
{
    return(n);
}
else
{
    return(fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
}
}

int main()
{
int n,i=0;
cout<<"Input the number of terms for Fibonacci Series:";
cin>>n;
cout<<"\nFibonacci Series is as follows\n";

while(i<n)
{
    cout<<" "<<fibonacci(i);
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
//use this one it is easy
```